# Fixed Menu at the top and a banner

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can I have a fixed menu at the top regardless of strolling down?
This is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-only-g1svw?file=/src/styles.css:247-357

If I'll try this css:

```
#header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2409545.jpg");
}
```

The banner disappears:

[image]

with `position: sticky;` this is what it looks like:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to `position:fixed` or `position:sticky`? See [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: @showdev with  `sticky` it does not do anything. with `fixed`, it does not work too. I've posted what it looks like with the `position: sticky`

Comment: Please add the updated CSS and relevant HTML to provide a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code shown here doesn't seem to match your codesandbox.

Comment: you should put your menu in a separate tag (component) and set position: fixed. now you have too much elements included with your menu.

Comment: see this https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-only-forked-ze65i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#navigator { 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1000; 
}
```